# Is PCIe IO address space meaningless for ARM-based system?

Tags: arm, pcie

According to [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169100&seqNum=6), the PCI Express TLP (Transaction Layer Packet) can target 4 different address spaces.

[image]

My question is about the IO and memory address spaces.

As we know, the PCI specification was first developed by Intel. And Intel's x86 processor has 2 major address spaces: **IO and memory**. I think that's why the PCI Express transactions can target 2 kinds of locations in *system IO map* and *system memory map*. Is it some kind of x86-specific *lineage*?

But how about ARM-based system? AFAIK there's no IO address space for ARM processors.

Does that mean the PCI Express IO address space is meaningless for ARM-based system?

Thanks.

### ADD 1 --- 9:18 2023/4/19

A related thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75265993/is-pci-cf8h-cfch-io-port-addresses-only-applicable-to-processors-with-an-io-ad

Some quote:

> The method for generating configuration cycles is host dependent. In IA machines, special I/O ports are used. On other platforms, the PCI configuration space can be memory-mapped to certain address locations corresponding to the PCI host bridge in the host address domain.

Answer (score 5):

> But how about ARM-based system? AFAIK there's no IO address space for ARM processors.

ARM-based systems that fully support PCI spec still support I/O transfers. The I/O space is then mapped into memory somewhere.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation, but the ARM Firmware Suite Reference Guide does have functions such as [uHALr_PCIIORead32](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0102/g/pci-management-library/-hal-pci-function-descriptions/uhalr-pciioread32?lang=en) to access I/O space.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. I will elaborate about it later.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Yep, IIRC these are the requisite memory-mapped accesses wrapped in an interface that clearly indicates the intent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The I/O address space support is included for x86, and ARM does not even have instructions to access such a separate address space.

Even in the x86 world, the I/O space was never extended beyond the 16-bit limit, and almost all PCIe "I/O" ranges are memory mapped. The only PCIe devices that support the I/O space do so because they need to be compatible with old x86 devices such as (non-USB) serial/parallel port or VGA.